# Static factory pattern with inheritance and type hints

Tags: php, inheritance, type-hinting, static-factory, named-constructor

I'm trying to make a class `Developer` which is a subclass of `Person`.
I want both of them to use the static factory pattern (or "named constructors").

I've seen some examples of that pattern, but none of them using inheritance.

**Question 1**
In the examples they make the constructor method always private.
Is it ok to make it protected in order to be called from the child constructor?
Or should I address the problem making the constructors always private, and trying to build the inheritance calling the parent's `create` method from the child's `create` method?

**Question 2**
When I try to instantiate either class Person or Developer, I'm getting the error below. Why?

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Developer::create(string $name, string $surname, ?int $yearsOfExperience = NULL, ?string $preferredLanguage = NULL): Developer must be compatible with Person::create(string $name, string $surname): Person in InheritanceTest.php on line 57
```

It works when I delete the `: self` type hints in both `create` methods, but I don't understand why are they incompatibles, if `Developer` is a child class of `Person`.

Thanks in advance.

```php
<?php

class Person
{
    protected $name;
    protected $surname;

    protected function __construct(string $name, string $surname)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->surname = $surname;
    }

    public static function create(string $name, string $surname): self
    {
        // Some validation

        if($name == ''){
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('A person name can not be empty.');
        }

        if($surname == ''){
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('A person surname can not be empty.');
        }

        return new self($name, $surname);
    }
}

class Developer extends Person
{
    protected $yearsOfExperience;
    protected $preferredLanguage;

    protected function __construct(string $name, string $surname, ?int $yearsOfExperience, ?string $preferredLanguage)
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $surname);

        $this->yearsOfExperience = $yearsOfExperience;
        $this->preferredLanguage = $preferredLanguage;
    }

    public static function create(string $name, string $surname, ?int $yearsOfExperience = null, ?string $preferredLanguage = null): self
    {
        // Some validation

        if($yearsOfExperience < 0){
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('The years of experience can not be negative.');
        }

        if($preferredLanguage == ''){
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('The preferred language can not be empty.');
        }

        return new self($name, $surname, $yearsOfExperience, $preferredLanguage);
    }
}
```

Comment: The return-type of `Person::create():self` (i.e. return-type Person) !== `Developer::create():self` (return-type Developer). `Developer::create() : Person { class code here }` should work just fine.

Comment: @jibsteroos Yes, that would work, but the Developer's create method is meant to return an instance of Developer, overwriting the Person's create method. An easy way would be to make methods with different names for example (createPerson, createDeveloper), but I think I misunderstood something with this pattern and there has to be a right way to address this.

Comment: `$dev = Developer::create('alex', 'pearson', 3, 'c++');` then `var_dump($dev)` shows it is `object(Developer)#2 (4) {...}`

Comment: @jibsteroos You're right! I thing PHP should recognize that `Developer` extends `Person`, and allow it to be the return hint for the create method. Instead of that, it returns a `Developer` instance when the method return hint is `Person`, which has no sense for me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: True, it's weird, not sure it's supposed to be like this, possibly a bug...

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**

> In the examples they make the constructor method always private.
>   Is it ok to make it protected in order to be called from the child constructor?

You have to make it protected. Otherwise child will not be allowed to call the parent's method.

**Question 2:**

> It works when I delete the : self type hints in both create methods, but I don't understand why are they incompatibles, if Developer is a child class of Person.

Try using `static` instead of `self`. It might work, but I am not sure. But you will still have notice (or warning, don't remember) because factory method in Developer has different parameters than Person. In PHP this is allowed but not recommended.

Comment: The problem flagged by the error is that the return type declaration in Class Developer::create() must be the same as declared by `Person::create() : self`. `self` is an object of type Person in this case. Thus, `Developer::create() : Person { class code here }` should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Q1: I know the parent's constructor has to be protected in order to be able to call it from the child. What I mean is: which is the right way to address the problem (inheritance with static factory)? Building the inheritance with the constructors? Or with the static methods? Q2: where should I use static instead of self?